# Hodge star operator evaluated at an orthonormal basis (Proposition 1.2.20 Huybrechts)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, exterior-algebra

We want to show:

$$*(e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k})=\epsilon e_{j_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{j_{n-k}}$$

where $\epsilon$ is the sign of the permutation $i_1 \cdots i_k \bar i_1 \cdots \bar i_{n-k}.$

The book doesn't provide any short of proof but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Formal_definition_for_k-vectors) we look the Gram determinant of $$\det(e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k}\wedge e_{j_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{j_{n-k}}).$$

I don't care so much about how we get the sign, but how we deduct the fact that $*(e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k})=\epsilon e_{j_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{j_{n-k}}$ by looking the Gram determinant ?

Comment: First, your indices in the first sentence are not consistent. Forget Wikipedia. What is Huybrechts’s definition of the star operator?

Comment: @TedShifrin  It sends a k-form $\beta$ to $*\beta$, an ($n-k$)-form and it's determined by $a\wedge *\beta=<a,b>$vol, where also $a$ is $k-$form.

Comment: @TedShifrin My original idea was to take $\beta=e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k}$ and $a=e_{j_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{j_{n-k}}$ then since we have an orthonormal basis $a\wedge *\beta=0$ thus $a= *\beta$. The problem is $a$ is not a k-form, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Al.G. I am not following, of course $k$ can be chosen arbitrary but since we pick $\beta$ to be a $k$ form $a$ must be also, in my logic $a$ is an $n-k$ form.

Comment: @Al.G. Ah I see now, this is better. But how we account for the sign in that logic ?

Comment: I removed my comments here so we can clean up space because it's all in the answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you defined $*\beta$ indirectly by the property $$\forall \alpha\in\bigwedge^k \mathbb F^n: \alpha\wedge *\beta=\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle \textrm{vol}$$ where I expect that $\textrm{vol}$ is defined by $\textrm{vol}=e_1\wedge\ldots\wedge e_n$ (the *unpermuted* basis - note that the indices run from 1 to n, not from $i_1$ to $i_n$). Note that there is no choice of $\alpha$ to state this definition - $\alpha$ is not a free (independent) variable, it is bound by the $\forall$ quantifier. Therefore, when applying it, we are free to plug in whatever $\alpha$s we want.

Take $\alpha = \beta = e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k}$. Then $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle =1$ and
$$e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_k}\wedge *\beta = \alpha\wedge*\beta=\textrm{vol}.$$

Note that the left-hand side uses the *permuted* basis, so to extract $*\beta$ from this expression we have to write $\textrm{vol}$ (the RHS) in terms of the permuted basis, too. By permuting terms in $e_1\wedge\ldots\wedge e_n$ (with the permutation $i:\{1...n\}\to\{1...n\}$) we get $\epsilon \;e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_n}$, where the constant factor $\epsilon$ is the *sign* of the permutation $i$. It pops up because of the antisymmetry of the wedge product. Therefore,

$$e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_k}\wedge *\beta = \epsilon \;e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_n}.$$

Now we wish to equate the rightmost $n-k$ terms to get the desired result $*\beta=\epsilon\;e_{i_{k+1}}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_n}$.

---

Unfortunately this doesn't work unless we prove $*\beta$ has no summands containing any of $e_{i_1},\ldots,e_{i_k}$. That is, right now we only know $$*\beta\in\epsilon\;e_{i_{k+1}}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_n} + \textrm{span} \{e_{\sigma_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge e_{\sigma_{n-k}} : \sigma_j=i_j\textrm{ for some } j \}$$

(It may be easier to imagine it in 2D: $e_1\wedge \xi=e_1\wedge e_2$ does not necessarily imply $\xi=e_2$, it only implies $\xi\in e_2+\textrm{span}\{e_1\}$).

We can easily rule out the excess span though, by applying $\alpha\wedge*\beta=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\textrm{vol}$ with $\alpha$ ranging over its basis:

$$\langle e_{\sigma_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge e_{\sigma_{n-k}}, \beta\rangle = 0 \textrm{ if } \sigma_j=i_j\textrm{ for some } j$$
holds for any permutation $\sigma$ because a scalar product between multivectors consisting of different basis vectors is zero (just like in 3D $\langle e_1\wedge e_2, e_2\wedge e_3\rangle=0$). Therefore the excess span in our conclusion about $*\beta$ plays no role and $*\beta$ is just $\epsilon\;e_{i_{k+1}}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{i_n}$.

---

You may find it interesting that this is also a proof of *existence* of $*\beta$. The definition of $*\beta$ you took only states a property of an imaginary object $*\beta$. The statement we prove here gives a formula for it over the basis of $\bigwedge^k \mathbb F^n$ (we did this by taking $\beta=e_{i_1} \wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_k}$ over any permutation $i$), and by linear extension $*$ becomes a linear operator $*:\bigwedge^k \mathbb F^n\to \bigwedge^{n-k} \mathbb F^n$.
Since the defining property of $*\beta$ depends linearly on $\beta$ (in the second place of the scalar product), we confirm that the linearly extended $*$ satisfies the defining property over all of $\bigwedge^k \mathbb F^n$ (and not just the basis vectors), thus proving existence of $*\beta$ for all $\beta$.

Comment: Unfortunately the last step here is false. Even in 2D, $e_1\wedge e_2 = e_1\wedge \alpha$ does not imply $\alpha=e_2$. It only means $\alpha = e_2 + \lambda e_1$ where $\lambda$ can be any scalar. To uniquely fix the value of $*\beta$ we have to use the scalar product again.

Comment: I just checked and we have to probe $*\beta$ with all choices of $\alpha$ in $\alpha\wedge *\beta$, so that we get a unique value for $*\beta$. I'll write it out in the answer later today.

Comment: I also thought of that, not only for one value. But I wasn't sure, as the definition in the book is not very clear. Thats the reason I asked here.

Comment: I am going to uncheck your answer temporarily just in case someone more experienced in the material wants to help.

Comment: Hint: It's enough to probe your candidate for $\ast\beta$ for all members of the chosen orthonormal basis of $\bigwedge^{n-k}$.

Comment: I did it somewhat manually after wrestling with it for some time and trying to understand what is happening, please have a look :) I suppose an entirely coordinate-based approach would look simpler and shorter, but I hope you find my way at least geometrically illuminating.

Comment: @Al.G. I just got off work, and by a quick look, this seems to put all the pieces together.  But I am going to look at it more thoroughly tomorrow. That also answers that * is well-defined? I mean, the operator doesn't depend on the choice of $a$, or we range over all k forms $a$ ?

Comment: @Al.G. And I agree it feels like there is a "cleaner" way to prove this, but our approach seems fine as well.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your follow up question, please tell me if it answers it. In short, no, $*\beta$ does not depend on $\alpha$, because $\alpha$ is a bound variable, but yes, we (almost) prove $*\beta$ is well-defined once we realize that both our formula and the definition are linear in $\beta$.